# How to fix radiogroup alignments in mobile devices. I want to align on the top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a radio button group. I can align them properly in large devices but in mobile view, the radio button is coming in the middle of the text.But i want to align at the top of the text.

<[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rQEY.png)div class="form-check form-check-inline col-lg-12">

Comment: provide the HTML and CSS to better understand your issue. We have no way of knowing what styles or markup hierarchy might be the cause of this issue - it this is abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Until you provide the actual code, as a baseline idea, place the text and the input within a `label` and use `vertical-align: baseline`.

```
input[type="radio"]{
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```